# How can i add these to get their total grade?

Tags: mysql, sql, computation

I already got their percentage for attendance to exam, i cant add all these to compute their total grade, it says in error unknown column 'attpercent' in 'fieldlist'

Comment: Hello Please give us your table structure, data sample and the query which is giving the error.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions